# Можно ли на clang++ написать десктоп?

Tags: c++, clang, фреймворк, wxwidgets, clang++

Недавно перешёл с C# на C++, набрался там много практики по ООП, паттернам, информатике и т.д. Я скачал компилятор clang++, с консольными приложениями работает очень хорошо. Теперь пытаюсь создать проект, используя wxWidgets. Ограничивается ли этот фреймворк конкретными компиляторами, а если подробнее: можно ли на clang++ собрать wxWidgets проект?

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Supported_Platforms Что-то страницу там давно никто не обновлял. Но clang наверняка тоже подойдет.

Comment: Откуда вы установили кланг? Вы используете его из visual studio, или нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я использую code::blocks и чаще notepad++ (просто он мне нравится), а установил я его с официального репозитория на гитхабе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang на Windows обычно ставится в пару к другому компилятору - к MinGW GCC или к MSVC (компилятор от Visual Studio), и использует некоторые библиотеки от них. Оффициальная сборка Clang-а по умолчанию использует MSVC, так что если она у вас работает, значит MSVC уже стоит.

Как ставить библиотеки - ищите инструкцию для MinGW или MSVC, и повторяйте то же самое с Clang-ом.

---

Раз вы не пользуетесь Visual Studio, то зависеть от MSVC выглядит странно. Я бы советовал поставить MinGW из [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

- Сносите оффициальный кланг.
- Ставите MSYS2 по ссылке выше.
- Запускаете его ярлыком `MSYS2 UCRT64`. Если сделано правильно, в открышейся консоли будет написано `UCRT64` фиолетовыми буквами. ([подробнее тут](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/))
- Обновляетесь командой `pacman -Syuu`. Если при этом консоль закроется - открыть заново и повторить команду для завершения обновления.
- Ставите себе Clang (эта версия по умолчанию использует библиотеки от MinGW), GDB (отладчик), и wxWidgets.

  ```
  pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-clang mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-wxwidgets3.2-msw mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb
  ```
- Теперь пробуем собрать пример [отсюда](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) (полный код в самом конце статьи).

  ```
  clang++ my_code.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
  ```

  Обратите внимание на обратные кавычки. Это запускает команду `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`, и подставляет ее вывод как флаги `clang++`.

  Запускаем получившийся файл командой `./a.exe`, и видим тестовое окно.
- У меня при компиляции вылезла куча странных предупреждений. Глушим их.

  Для этого в примере находим `#include <wx/wx.h>`, и обкладываем его вот так:

  ```
  #ifdef __clang__
  #pragma clang diagnostic push
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wignored-attributes"
  #endif
  #include <wx/wx.h>
  #ifdef __clang__
  #pragma clang diagnostic pop
  #endif
  ```

  Перезапускаем компиляцию и убеждаемся в отсутсвии предупреждений.
- Пробуем запустить `a.exe` не из MSYS2, а мышкой из проводника. Скорее всего ничего не запустится, пока вы не добавите `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` первым элементом в PATH.
- Теперь повторяем то же самое из CodeBlocks.

  Лезем в настройки, и исправляем путь до компилятора. Он должен показывать на содержимое папки `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`. То же самое с путем до отладчика.

  В настройки проекта вписываем флаги компилятора. В `compiler flags -> other` вывод `wx-config --cxxflags`, а в `linker flags -> other` вывод `wx-config --libs`.

  Пробуем скомпилировать и запустить из CodeBlocks.